# Listing S3 Bucket newest file with Bash Script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi am new to the world of shell scripting, and am Running into a couple of issues. I am writing a bash script that calls two AWS S3 Buckets, and lists the newest files that have been uploaded. 
On the 'long run', those two files have to be downloaded, and using CLI copied to 2 existing tables within an RDS PostgreSQL Database.
So far, this is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash


printf "Looking up newest files added...\n";

AUTO= $(aws s3 ls bucketx --recursive | sort | tail -n 1| awk '{print $4}');
IMMO= $(aws s3 ls buckety --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}');

echo AUTO;
echo IMMO;
```

Problem is, and this is what I don't get, when I execute the AWS commands directly in the terminal, and goes well and behaves the way it should. But within the script, I get the following errors:

```
Looking up newest files added...
./shellTest.sh: line 6: bucketx/14.9.2016.csv: No such file or directory
./shellTest.sh: line 7: buckety/14.9.2016.csv: No such file or directory
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Is it a logic-problem or 'just' a syntactical problem?
I was expecting the 'echo' command to just  print out the content of the variables x and y, but instead nothing is printed..

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you want in AUTO is the value of the latest key so you need to have a string

```
AUTO="$(aws s3 ls bucketx --recursive | sort | tail -n 1| awk '{print $4}')"
IMMO="$(aws s3 ls buckety --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}')"
```

so `AUTO` and `IMMO` will hold the value (the string value of the key) - if you omit the quote, the system will try to find the reference and will complain the file does not exist locally

To show the value you then need to have

```
echo $AUTO
echo $IMMO
```

see below

This one does not work

```
$ AUTO= $(aws s3 ls <bucket> --recursive | sort | tail -n 1| awk '{print $4}');
-bash: database/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip: No such file or directory
```

but this one is ok

```
$ AUTO="$(aws s3 ls <bucket> --recursive | sort | tail -n 1| awk '{print $4}')"
$ echo $AUTO
database/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip
```

Comment: hum .. this is weird because it works for me locally when I make the change (using the quotes) while I have the same error your reported when I dont have quote (use your code)

Comment: need to remove semi-colon in script too, fixed my message

Comment: Is it a bash thing? Just checked, I am running GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) BTW allready removed the semi-colons, the error still persists

Comment: GOT IT! there was a white-space between the = and the first "... thank you very much for your help !!!!